# Pass variable to Linux 'awk'

Tags: linux, bash

How can I pass a previously defined variable to awk in bash? For example,

`hostname="server1"
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F":" '{print $1 " of $hostname"}`

And the expected output is

```
root of server1
sys of server1
......
......  // for all user accounts
```

But what I get is

```
root of $hostname
sys of $hostname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a quoting problem:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

(from [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html)).

All you need to do is to place `$hostname` outside the single quotes:

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F":" '{print $1 " of '$hostname'"}'
```

or use double quotes and escape some characters with `\`:

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F":" "{print \$1 \" of $hostname\"}"
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` has a built in variable option with `-v`.

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F":" -v hostname="server1" '{print $1 " of " hostname}
```